# Fill Page Excess Using CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute

I am trying to create a div that will fill any empty space at the bottom of a page if there is any, or disappear if the content of the page extends to/past the bottom. I know this can be done using java, but I would like to stick to CSS as much as possible with as few wrappers as possible.

I have experimented with a few different methods but nothing has worked out so far and most of what I have come across is sticky footers, tables, and filling the excess on specific div elements (which this isn't since I want it to work on the whole page at the body/html level).

The furthest I have gotten (which still doesn't work) is to try absolute positioning with alternated top & bottom values, but setting `top: inherit` and then `bottom: 0px` just doesn't play well... Example: http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/6/

The basic problem comes down to: 1. Keep the top of the div where it would usually be just after the previous div 2. Extend the bottom of the div to the bottom of the page 3. Vary with content and page size changes 4. Disappear if there is no excess space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Update: So far everyone seems to think it's a job for Javascript, so I came up with this quick jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/7/ Feel free to rip me a new one on the code as I always appreciate the learning opportunity :)

Comment: are you expecting http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/3/ ???

Comment: @Beginner only if the "fill" area adjusted to the page height and ran from the bottom of the previous div to the bottom of the page without extending the page, but disappeared if the page content was enough to fill the window... So yes I am expecting the "fill" area to take up more space than my original jsfiddle, but the simple example you posted is not the end result I am looking for.

Comment: @Koopa then what should be the expected result?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe The "fill" div should extend from the end of the previous div to the bottom of the page but not extend the page at all, and disappear completely if the previous content is enough to fill the window. In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/2/ the "fill" div should extend up to the red. In the example the Beginner gave, the "fill" area extends the page to achieve coverage and does not vary at all with window size change or content size change.

Comment: where is the question?????

Comment: @NoobEditor Here is an update: http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/6/ How do you make it do that? How do you make a div that will extend from the end of the previously final div down to the bottom of the page without extending the page, and if the content of the page without this div is larger than the window size, will drop down to a zero height? Perhaps a really easy way of putting this is: If you have a very little content on a page, how do you make a div that will automatically take up the rest of the space? But if that page gets big will disappear?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something for background purpose here, I would use a div, that stretches over the complete visible area (if the visible area is as large as the content, it's just hidden behind the content).

Then it would be something like that here: http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/4/ http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/5/

Here's the css code I used:

```
#content {
    background-color: #F00;
    /* The overflow is to keep margins of the first and last element in here. Disable it and you get what I mean ;) */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fill {
    background-color: #00F;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Here's a bit more info on that: http://codecamel.com/fullheight

I can imagine, that I sometimes had to use `min-height` instead of `height` for the body or html ... but can't remember when or why ...

Comment: Thank you, but this is not at all what I am trying to do. The min-height was just there so that the div would not disappear. I am trying to make a div that will extend from the bottom of the previous div down to the bottom of the page without extending it further and will disappear if the previous content of the page is enough to extend it past the window size. Here is an update: http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/6/

Comment: Koopa, I think that's just possible with tables ... or JavaScript. Btw: I would really like to try this application on some other devices after it's ready ... f.e. on my mobile phone ...

Comment: Agreed. You can't fill a page with a div with no content in it using only HTML and CSS, you can only fake it as @SimonSimCity suggests.

Comment: The problem with doing it with tables is if the content is bigger than the window. I could put the whole thing inside a table wrapper, but that just seems really sloppy to me... In java I could just take the content height and subtract it from the window height, but I'm trying to keep my java down to a minimum as well (as my last design got really buggy) so I figured I'd see if anybody had something clean CSS wise before I revert back...

Comment: Koopa, just so to have that said: You don't really use Java here, do you? You mean JavaScript, don't you? `Java is to JavaScript like ham is to hamster.` http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/02/15/java-vs-javascript

Comment: @SimonSimCity Correct, JavaScript & usually jQuery... I'm mostly self taught & the few things I've done for "clients" **cough**friends**cough** they don't know what is what so I've never had to correct myself on java/javascript. I did a quick jQuery solution to my question... Still rather have css, but this will do for now... Feel free to rip it apart :) http://jsfiddle.net/V4RnC/7/